# What is a clobber?

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, inline-assembly

Clang [`TargetInfo`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TargetInfo.html) has a method called `getClobbers`:

> Returns a string of target-specific clobbers, in LLVM format.

So, what is a clobber?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A clobbered register is a register which is trashed i.e. modified in unpredictable way by inline assembler. This usually happens when you need a temp. register or use particular instruction which happens to modify some register as a by-product.

Usually programmer explicitly declares registers which are clobbered by his inline asm code but some may be considered to be trashed by default and that's where `getClobbers` come into play.

`getClobbers` returns empty result for most targets. On MIPS GCC has historically not used `$1` in generated code so most programmers didn't bother to declare it as clobbered. To reduce portability costs, LLVM considers `$1` to be always clobbered in inline asm. Another example is arithmetic flags register (cc) which is [considered to be always clobbered by inline asm](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/be39636d9f68c437c8a2c2e7a225c4aed4663e78/gcc/config/i386/i386.c#L21553) by GCC on i386 and x86_64 targets.

Comment: Might be worth adding that "trashed" here means the assembler code needs to use the registers (a register could be seen as a very fast temporary variable built into the CPU instead of being on a separate RAM chip if you're unfamiliar with assembler), and so will not preserve the values the caller put into them.

Comment: @uliwitness Thanks, added.

Comment: i386 and amd64 gcc (and clang I'm pretty sure) implicitly clobber condition codes, `"cc"`, in asm statements because many integer instructions unavoidably write them.  I know you're not trying to make an exhaustive list, but that's one for a major ISA.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, that's a good addition to the answer. I haven't yet found code in Clang which does so mentioned only GCC.