# Extended Inline Assembly in C++: What exactly are the clobbered registers?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, g++, inline-assembly

I am learning how to write extended inline assembly in C++, and so far I feel I have a pretty good understanding of what the inputs and outputs are in the extended inline assembly syntax. I am still a little confused however, as to what the clobbered registers are supposed to mean (i am following this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5318/Extended-Inline-Assembly-in-GCC).

```
asm ( "assembly code"
           : output operands                  /* optional */
           : input operands                   /* optional */
           : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
);
```

In the documentation, it states the following about the clobbered registers (registers modified):

> It is not mandatory to specify the list of clobbered registers to use,
> we can leave that to GCC and GCC’s optimization scheme do the needful.

Yet in so many of the extended inline examples I am seeing, there's always something placed in the clobbered register list. So my question is, do I need to put anything in the clobbered register list, and if so, what are the values I put in there (do I just put every register I am pushing data into there)? Below is the list of possible inputs and outputs (from the documentation-is it the same for clobbered registers)?

```
g - let the compiler decide which register to use for the variable
q - load into any available register from eax, ebx, ecx, edx
r - same as q but includes esi and edi
a - load into the eax register
b - load into the ebx register
c - load into the ecx register
d - load into the edx register
f - load into the floating point register
D - load into the edi register
S - load into the esi register
```

Furthermore, I see a lot of examples putting in "cc" as the clobbered register, indicating that the flags register is set (what exactly does this mean and how do I know when the flags register is set)?

Comment: You need to put anything you change that is not an output.

Comment: "It is not mandatory to specify the list of clobbered registers to use, we can leave that to GCC and GCC’s optimization scheme do the needful." That isn't true. Find a better reference.

Comment: @Jester Gotcha. I guess the only thing I am confused by is is when the flags register is set (when to put "cc" in the clobbered register)

Comment: The instruction set reference documents how each instruction affects the flags.

Comment: As Jester points out you have to look at the instruction set reference of each of the instructions in the inline assembly to determine if they may be potentially changed. On x86 the `cc` clobber is essentially unused. Specifying it doesn't hurt and it may provide a kind of documentation. If it was ever supported in the future then inline assembly that did specify it would be able to take advantage of that feature.

Comment: The gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers) have some explanations: *While the compiler is aware of changes to entries listed in the output operands, the inline asm code may modify more than just the outputs. For example, calculations may require additional registers, or the processor may overwrite a register as a side effect of a particular assembler instruction. In order to inform the compiler of these changes, list them in the clobber list.*

Comment: @Jester: For i386 / x86-64 targets, a `"cc"` (condition-codes) clobber is implicit in every asm statement.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica:  There are some correct guides / tutorials linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a clobber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899881/what-is-a-clobber)

Comment: @PeterCordes There was [talk](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2016-05/msg00419.html) about changing basic asm to clobber memory.  The discussion thread peters out and I don't see a final commit message, so maybe they didn't do it?  I sort of lost touch on this.  The docs still have my original *It also does not know about side effects of the assembler code, such as modifications to memory or registers* text, so perhaps not.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Oh, probably I was wrong about Basic asm having an implicit `"cc"` clobber, thanks for the link.  That was an assumption on my part, not tested because there's never a reason to use Basic asm in any context where Extended is legal. It's not like we *want* people to start using Basic asm inside non-naked functions.  So I assume there's also no implicit `"memory"` clobber either.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment which mistakenly says that `asm("clc");` could be safe inside a function.  Never use Basic Asm in a context where Extended Asm is allowed: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended. 
 (And https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm at all if you can achieve the desired effect another way.)  The code in the question is using an Extended asm statement, so nvm this tangent.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: happened to find a litmus test for `asm("")` not having an implicit `"memory"` clobber (while looking for a duplicate for something else) - [Why can't local variable be used in GNU C basic inline asm statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/106532558) - https://godbolt.org/z/eWczj1 confirms that current trunk GCC doesn't treat `asm("")` as clobbering memory.  A similar test for being able to break something with `asm("clc")` might be possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes Somewhere in one of those threads, you can see me making a pitch to kill Basic Asm In a Function completely.  My proposal was to wean people off it by starting to issue warnings for such code, increasing in severity over a couple of releases.  I even submitted some code+doc patches to that effect.  Indeed, that's why I wrote that "How to Convert basic to extended asm" article.  Didn't find a lot of supporters for the idea.  I understand the idea of backward compatibility.  But discouraging new development from using this kludgy turd seemed like a reasonable plan.

Comment: I tried but didn't succeed in experimenting with Basic `asm("nop")` getting between add and setc for example. https://godbolt.org/z/1jY9hx.  So no definitive proof either way.

Comment: @PeterCordes IIRC, `asm("")` was to be special cased (but I don't remember in what way).  Changing foo() to use "nop" changes the results of your test (but not in 4.1.2).  And this is why I was opposed to this change.  It's weird, it's different behavior than it used to be in earlier gcc versions, may or may not be consistent with other implementations of asm and is (apparently) undocumented.  Grr.  Shoulda killed the entire thing.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Yeah, I thought I noticed a difference between `""` and `"nop"` or maybe even `"# comment"` at one point.  Does that happen with Extended asm, too, or is `asm("# compiler barrier here" ::: "memory")` always the same as `""`?  If it's only Basic asm, that's not very important, nobody should ever use it inside functions. 
 (And agreed, GCC should warn about Basic asm inside non-naked function; might get naive users to google sooner, and maybe save Stack Overflow some noise.)

Comment: @PeterCordes [Here's](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24414) the bug where they checked in the change.  I can point you at several discussion threads from that time where I proposed: Just doc'ing the current behavior, docs+warning about uses of BAIF, flat out removing BAIF.  Several people agreed that there were problems with it, but wouldn't commit to *any* course of action to address it.  In the end, the apparent fix was to change the behavior in a way that (might be how) people always expected it to work, but not document anything.  That's roughly when I stopped working on gcc.